# Applying tags to a CFN stack using Azure DevOps pipeline - list?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Following on from my question the other day...

[Passing an object into a template in Azure DevOps pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391598/passing-an-object-into-a-template-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

I am now facing the problem where I'm trying to use the pipeline to apply tags to the AWS CloudFormation stack that gets created from the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Here's the pipeline (some bits of it) :-

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
parameters:
- name: stackparams
  type: object
  default:
    - displayname: AWS Test User Account
      awscredentials: TESTAWS-BuildUser
      templatefile: ./Test/TestApp/ConsoleSwitchRolesGroupsPolicies.yml
      templateparametersfile: ./Test/TestApp/demoparams.json
      tags:
        - tag1
        - tag2
        - Managed=Cloudformation
stages:
- stage: ProdDeploy  # name of the stage (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  displayName: Production Deploy  # friendly name to display in the UI
  jobs:
    - deployment: DeveloperRoles   # name of the deployment job (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
      displayName: Manage Developer Roles using Cloudformation  # friendly name to display in the UI
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      environment: aws-test-appaccount-structure  # target environment name and optionally a resource name to record the deployment history; format: <environment-name>.<resource-name>
      strategy:
        runOnce:    #rolling, canary are the other strategies that are supported
          deploy:
            steps:
              - template : ./Templates/CfnUpdateStack/CfnUpdateStack.yml
                parameters:
                  stackparams: ${{ parameters.stackparams }}
                  runRolesGroupsPolicies: ${{ parameters.runRolesGroupsPolicies }}
```

Here's the template :-

```
# CfnUpdateStack.yml
parameters:
- name: stackparams
  type: object
- name: runRolesGroupsPolicies
  type: boolean

steps:
- ${{ each stackparam in parameters.stackparams }}:
  - task: CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
    displayName: ${{ stackparam.displayname }}
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: ${{ stackparam.awscredentials }}
      regionName: 'eu-west-1'
      stackName: 'ConsoleSwitchRolesGroupsPolicies'
      templateSource: 'file'
      templateFile: ${{ stackparam.templatefile }}
      templateParametersFile: ${{ stackparam.templateparametersfile }}
      tags: |
            Component=RoleUserAccess
            ${{ stackparam.tags }}
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.runRolesGroupsPolicies }}', true)
```

When I run this I *only* get the first tag Component=RoleUserAccess. I have managed to get it working, but using this horrendous ugly method of using a variable (not a param) and putting a blank line between each tag. It does work though!

```
Versions
variables:
- name: tags
  value: "tag1

          tag2

          Managed=Cloudformation"
```

We have around 20 tags for each resource, so it gets pretty messy. I have cut it down to make the question simpler to read.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add an array (tags) to an array (stackparams), I don't think it's correct. You may try the following syntax:

```
    # CfnUpdateStack.yml
    
    parameters:
    - name: 'tags'
      type: object
      default: {}
    - name: 'displayname'
      type: string
      default: ''
    - name: 'awscredentials'
      type: string
      default: ''
    - name: 'templatefile'
      type: string
      default: ''
    - name: 'templateparametersfile'
      type: string
      default: ''
   steps:
    
    
    
    # azure-pipelines.yml
    
    
    - template: CfnUpdateStack.yml
      parameters:
        tags: 
        - tag1
        - tag2
        - Managed=Cloudformation  
        displayname: AWS Test User Account
        awscredentials: TESTAWS-BuildUser
        templatefile: ./Test/TestApp/ConsoleSwitchRolesGroupsPolicies.yml
        templateparametersfile: ./Test/TestApp/demoparams.json
    
    - template: CfnUpdateStack.yml
      parameters:
        tags: 
        - tag1
        - tag2
        - Managed=Cloudformation  
        displayname: AWS Test User Account2
        awscredentials: TESTAWS-BuildUser2
        templatefile: ./Test/TestApp/ConsoleSwitchRolesGroupsPolicies2.yml
        templateparametersfile: ./Test/TestApp/demoparams2.json
```

Comment: I have tried as you suggest, but I always get an error message when trying to reference the tags within an "each" loop (possibly because it's already within another each loop). "While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key."

Comment: Could you share more yaml file you are using?

Comment: With my latest attempt I'm getting the error message "/Templates/CfnUpdateStack/CfnUpdateStack.yml (Line: 37, Col: 13): Unable to convert from Array to String. Value: Array
/Templates/CfnUpdateStack/CfnUpdateStack.yml (Line: 47, Col: 21): Unable to convert from Array to String. Value: Array"  Here's the code https://gist.github.com/sbutt/012ee8ef698261e54927b1bd8be875ad and https://gist.github.com/sbutt/8341d9e730ff13f99fce576f68cd5a0b

Comment: Could you also share the CfnUpdateStack.yml? The error indicated to this file.

Comment: That's the second gist that I shared.

Comment: Sorry I missed that link. `tags` are array, you should use it as `${{ each tags in parameters.tags }}` , then use ${{ tags }}.

Comment: I've already got a loop which goes around the stackparams object which gives me the displayname, templatefile, etc. However this array of tags would need to be within the iteration of the stackparams, as we're doing this for many accounts. I'm not sure how to get a loop within a loop working in YAML? Do I have to put the {{ each }} at the start of the line, or indent the same as the "tags: |" within the template?

Comment: yes I tried something like you suggested. Problem is we're looping through a list of accounts with "- displayName: Account 1" etc. How should I unpack the list of tags, when it's already looping through the accounts?

Comment: You could add your accounts as parameter and loop tags in each template in `azure-pipelines.yml` files in my example., instead of looping the accounts.  In addition, check the sample in this link to see whether it can help you use two loops as it mentaioned: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/each-expression.md.